# How to change my avatar in Hinduism chat?

Tags: support, chat

I need to change (maybe cached at server) my chat avatar in Hinduism chat only. How to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Every chat user has a parent site shown as "parent user". You have to change your parent site avatar and that same avatar is shown in chat.stackexchange.com also.

1. Click on your avatar in chat room.
2. Select user profile.
3. Click on parent site

[image: Image of chat profile with "parent user" underlined]

4. **Change the avatar on parent site. The avatar will be updated in chat in a few minutes**.

Changing profile picture is easy. Go to "Edit profile and settings" click on "Change Picture". Add an image your want to use as profile picture.